# Alignment problem with fancyhdr for a report page layout

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

I am trying to define a base class for some reports to share the same page layout. I use the `fancyhdr` package for creating the header and footer but I am experiencing some vertical alignment problems. I spent hours trying to figure out how to do what seems so simple in HTML. In the following images, I used the package `showframe` to help identifying the page layout.

Here is an image of what I would like to achieve:

[image: ![report base image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q7y8.png)

Here is an image of what I have right now:

[image: ![report base result]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JCKm.png)

Apart from the general page layout, I cannot vertically align the report name and date to the top with the image:

[image: ![report header alignment]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEu2R.png)

The page body overlaps the header:

[image: ![report body overlaps]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYMSG.png)

The page footer overlaps the body:

[image: ![report footer overlaps]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qn4b.png)

Finally, here is the Latex code used for the class:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{basereport}

% base class
\LoadClass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

% packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The UTF-8 encoding is specified.
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}

% debug frames
\usepackage{showframe}

% margins
% http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm
]{geometry}

% macro for images
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

% page style
% http://ctan.bppro.ca/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf
\pagestyle{fancy} % for page style

% page header
\fancyhf{} % reset header and footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % remove footer rule

\fancyhead[L]{
    \includegraphics[width=4cm, height=2cm, keepaspectratio=true]{universe.jpg}
}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{
    \large\textbf{
        \MakeUppercase{Report name}
        \linebreak
        2015-11-10
    }
}

% page footer
\fancyfoot[L]{
    \small\emph{Printed on \today\ at \currenttime}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{
    \small\emph{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

% commands
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

and the document:

```
\documentclass{basereport}
\begin{document}
\textcolor[rgb]{0,0,1}{
    \lipsum[1]
}
\end{document}
```

I tried to play with the length of those properties:

```
\hoffset
\voffset
\headheight
\textheight
\textwidth
\footskip
\headsep
```

EDIT: Here is what I got for using some of those properties:

```
\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{1cm}

\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.5cm}
```

[image: report base result with properties]

It seems like the `geometry` package is being overridden by `fancyheader`? I am not sure to understand the conflicts. If I ask for 1cm margins, why do I have the set `voffset`? Also, is there any way of specifying the header and footer heights, and let the body use the remainder of the document without having to set `textheight`? How to vertical align the text in the header to the top?

EDIT 2:

I set the properties in the `geometry` package declaration instead of manually as suggested and it helped a lot. I am still usure why the top value must include the `headheight` and `headsep` plus the desired margin value.

[image: report base result with geometry]

Two questions remains:

1) how to vertically align my header so the title and date are at the top?

2) how to remove the line under the footer which appears even if `footrulewidth` is set to `0.0pt`?

The updated code of the class for reference:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{basereport}

% base class
\LoadClass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}

% packages
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The UTF-8 encoding is specified.
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{helvet}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr} % for header and footer
\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}

% debug frames
\RequirePackage{showframe}

% margins
% http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf
\RequirePackage[
    headheight=30mm,
    headsep=5mm,
    footskip=10mm,
    top=45mm, 
    bottom=20mm, 
    left=10mm, 
    right=10mm
]{geometry}

% macro for images
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

% page style
% http://ctan.bppro.ca/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf
\pagestyle{fancy} % for page style

% page header
\fancyhf{} % reset header and footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % remove footer rule

\fancyhead[L]{
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true]{universe.jpg}
}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{
    \large\textbf{
        \MakeUppercase{Report name}
        \linebreak
        2015-11-10
    }
}

% page footer
\fancyfoot[L]{
    \small\emph{Printed on \today\ at \currenttime}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{
    \small\emph{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
}

% commands
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Your `headheight` and topmargin are too small, most likely

Comment: Don't you get a warning from fancyhdr that headheight is incorrect?

Comment: `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` would be better

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am doing some test on `sharelatex.com` to easily preview my changes and I do not get any warnings.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Should I change all my `usepackage` for `RequirePackage` or only the one for `fancyhdr`. I am trying to learn the best practices.

Comment: @jpmorin: All of them. And I think you have switched off the warnings on this sharelatex.com stuff.

Comment: It's normal to use `\RequirePackage` in class files and `\usepackage` in document preamble, but their definitions are (completely) identical so don't worry too much aboout that.

Comment: Ok, I will do that, thank you for the input. Also, I edited the post with what I achieved by setting the `headheight`. But for `topmargin`, it creates a huge space no matter what value I put.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You were right, there is a warning in the sharelatex logs file `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt)`.

Comment: The warning also tells you what the value needs to be as a minimum. Use that to set `headheight`. Only don't do page dimensions manually. Use `\usepackage[headheight=<whatever>, headsep=5mm, ...]{geometry}` and then don't specify dimensions manually. The package will then calculate everything correctly.

Comment: Your comments helped me a lot. I edited a last time the post about the `footrulewidth` not being "applied" and the vertical-alignment for the title in the header if by any chance you know how to do that. Hopefully I can contribute to this community in the future, once I have learned enough!

Comment: Don't load `showframe` and the line will disappear. One way to get the alignment is to use a single header consisting of a `minipage` of width `\textwidth`. Then include two `minipage`s within it, both top aligned and with `\hfill` in between. The first holds the image. The second the other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The basic error is that the `\headheight` length is too small, this leads to an overlapping at the top of the page header and the regular text.

`fancyhdr` will issue a warning and some recommendation about correct values on the console and in the log file.

Use `\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}` (or whatever appropiate value is reported by `fancyhdr`) or use `\usepackage[headheight=2cm,...]{geometry}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a solution with the elements of the header aligned. The trick is to use minipage in the left part of the header, and add `\vspace{0pt}` to the minipage.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[headheight=40.3pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

%\usepackage{showframe} % To adjust header and footer
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{flushright}
        {\Large \textbf{TOP Line}}\\
        {\normalsize Second line}\\
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}  
}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]